# Switch Content divs on break point

Tags: jquery, html, css, breakpoints

On this site : http://alumni.fgcu.edu/s/1630/index.aspx?sid=1630&gid=1&pgid=373 I am trying to get the left side column to move under the right columns content when the screen-size is under 768px.

I tried reversing the floats on the two divs (".split30left and .split70right").  I've even tried jQuery's resize feature to detect when the two divs have a width value of 100% to switch them around and I've had no luck.

Any questions let me know before down voting.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to change the order of the divs in your HTML, so split30left comes after split70right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pschueller is exactly right... swap the two divs in your html without changing any of the CSS and you should be fine:

```
<div class="split70right" id="indexRight">
    -- content --
</div>

<div class="split30left" id="indexLeft">
    -- content --
</div>
```

the floats will still keep the "split30left" div on the left side, and the other on the right.  If needed you can adjust the floats on your media query if it isn't acting right on screen widths smaller than 768px.

Comment: I was clearly over thinking the situation.  Thanks for the help.